# Custom slug in front of search URL

Tags: url-rewriting, search, urls

I'll try explain this the best I can...

I have a search form on my homepage:

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" class="form" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
    <label class="u-visuallyHidden" for="s">Search for property:</label>
    <input type="search" class="form-input search-bar-input" value="<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>" name="s" id="s" placeholder="enter location here" autocomplete="off" />

    <button type="submit" class="btn search-bar-btn" id="searchsubmit">
        <span class="u-verticalAlignMiddle"><i class="icon-search"></i> <span class="u-visuallyHidden">Search</span></span>
    </button>
</form>
```

And then there's more in-depth search form in my 'search.php' template that holds a number of hidden fields that relate to some user input selectors. The search results then take the `$_GET` request and I build a custom `$wp_query`.

Everything works fine...but, I'd like to change my search URL to something like:

```
http://mydomain.dev/student/?s=
```

I've tried to change the action to `esc_url( home_url( '/student/' ) )` but I just get a 404 when a search term is entered.

I've played around with the 'template_redirect' action and rewrite rules, but I don't want pretty permalinks because my refined search form adds a number of additional URL params. For example a users search could yield this URL:

```
http://mydomain.dev/?s=&letmc_type=professional&custom_locations=SomeCity&min_bedrooms=2&price_min=60&price_max=70
```

Also, is there a better way with WordPress of utilizing query args, rather than the `$_GET` superglobal?

Comment: @toscho I'm English :) less of the American English please....it's 'utilising'

Comment: Then refix it! :)

Answer (score 3):

None of the above worked for me. Found another solution by overwriting the search rewrite rules using the search_rewrite_rules filter.

1 - Add this to the functions.php of your theme:

```
add_filter( 'search_rewrite_rules', function($rules) {
    
     $new_rules = [];

     // New search slug here
     $new_search_slug = 'zoeken';
    
     foreach ($rules AS $key => $value){
        
         $new_rules[str_replace('search', $new_search_slug, $key)] = $value;
        
     }

     return $new_rules;

});
```

2 - Save the permalinks in the WordPress admin under Settings -> Permalinks.

Now the page https://www.mywebsite.com/zoeken/searchterm is showing the search results page.

Answer (score 1):

The default "pretty" alternative to `?s=` is `/search/` - you should be able to use that right now.

If you want to change it to student, add this to your functions.php file:

```
function re_rewrite_rules() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->search_base        = 'student';
}
add_action('init', 're_rewrite_rules');
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I've literally just done this step. Using a pretty permalink breaks my current system when I add all my custom URL params on

Comment: I really just need http://mydomain.dev/student/?s= to work correctly from both the homepage and the search results page

Comment: What you're asking is to mix a "pretty permalink" with a query arg and I'm just not sure that it could be done in this case. Normally the rewrite should work, unless you have something else already loading at  mydomain.dev/student/ (a page?)

Comment: There is a page....but I need to assign the 'search.php' template to it???

Comment: That'd probably be useless, you'd lose the intended functionality of the page (unless it's something like an index or - to the same purpose - a search result for a space character). You should give a bit more context - why it doesn't already work as intended or what exactly you're trying to achieve as a whole (as there seems to be another issue along the way).

Answer (score 1):

This works perfectly for me on my site: [nnn.com.ng](https://nnn.com.ng/). Other solution throw a 404 error for me.

```
/**
* initiate a change of the wordpress default search page slug to the new search page slug.
*/
add_action( 'init', 'dsfs' );

function dsfs()
{
    $GLOBALS['wp_rewrite']->search_base = '%your_search_string%';
}

/**
* redirect default search page slug to the new search page slug.
*/

function wpcs_url() {
    if ( is_search() && ! empty( $_GET['s'] ) ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url( "/your_search_string/" ) . urlencode( get_query_var( 's' ) ) );
        exit();
    }  
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpcs_url' );
```

You will need to add "%" before and after "your_search_string" (e.g. %student%) for it to work. You may need to flush the cache if it is a production site with a cache plugin.