# Custom Search on Custom Page while preserving the main search function

Tags: customization, search

Wordpress - Custom Search on Custom Page while preserving the standard search function.

Hi all,

I would like to create a custom search on a custom page on top of main search function. The additional one is supposed to be focused only on products.

*search-product.php*

```
$product_type = $_GET['post_type'];

$args = array(
    'post_type' => $product_type,
    'posts_per_page' => -1
);

$the_query = new WP_Query($args);

/* Start the Loop */
while ($the_query -> have_posts() ) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>


<h5><?php the_title(); ?></h5>

<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

*The form:*

```
<form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="<?php echo esc_url(home_url('/search-products/')); ?>">
        <div class="row align-items-center">
        <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="product">
        <input type="text" name="productname" value="" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Product Name..." class="searchForm form-control"> 


            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Szukaj</button>

        </div>
    </form>
```

When I define the post type within the php file, it displays the query as expected.
But I want to be able to modify the query on this page with URL instructions, however if I do something like this:
http://localhost/wordpress/search-product/?post_type=product

WP returns the "page not found" page, with a different template. I believe it's the default "search" template.

Now...
I know that I can/should modify the search.php file to make the whole thing work, BUT, I don't want to modify the main search.php (main query ? ).

I want to preseve the main search functionality, and have another custom one on top of it.

I have also utilized the template_include function as filter - however this returns a page, that visually is aligned with what I expect, however the head title is still "page not found".

I also tried to use the "pre_get_posts" hook, but also with no success.

I have spend lots of hours on this page to find the solutions, but all the answers include modifing the standard search.php file, but as mentioned, I do not want to modify the main search template.

Thanks!

Comment: So I suppose you already have created the custom product search page, and which you have assigned to be using the template named *search-product.php*? Can you add the search form code to your question?

Comment: Hi Sally. Yes, you are correct. I have added the search form code.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Now in the `form` there, remove the `<input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="product">`, and in *search-product.php*, change `$product_type = $_GET['post_type'];` to `$product_type = 'product';`. Because I think the field's `name` (i.e. `post_type`) conflicts with the standard `WP_Query` request. So either you change the `name` (to something like `cust_post_type`) or do like I've suggested, which is hard-code the value in *search-product.php*. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thans Sally! Unfortunately this is not solving the issue. I still get redirected to the page not found page, and no results are returned of course. It works if I change the home page index to this page, but I don't want to change the home index. Could it be that endpoints have something to do with it? Or maybe I am missing some filters in my plugin?

Comment: Which one did you try? Removed the `input` from the `form`, or renamed the `input` to another `name`? Or did you try both options?

Comment: You can also try this trick.. add `<input type="hidden" name="pagename" value="search-product" />` to the `form`, and make sure the `post_type` `input` is either removed from that `form` or change its `name` to something else. And then, set the form's `action` to `<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>`. But.. the page URL would look "ugly".

Comment: I've renamed the input to another name, and binded it via get with the query. If I remove the input altogether, it redirects me to the missing results page too.
Also another interesting observation - if I set the query to an empty wp_query, it returns only the page title. Like if there is a separate post index for that page, which only includes... of course, the current page. 
I like the idea with the additional value - sounds like an option. Maybe Ill then rewrite it to make it look "nice". Ill let you know.

Comment: I managed to find the solution Sally. This solved everything:
function search_rewrite_rules()
{
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->search_base        = 'Search Product';
}
add_action('search_rewrite_rules', 'template_chooser');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out, that the following solved my issue:

```
function search_rewrite_rules()
{
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->search_base        = 'Search Product';
}
add_action('init', 'search_rewrite_rules');
```

This hook moves the search_base to the given page, which enables everything I wanted to achieve.

Credit goes to the guy in this query:
[Custom slug in front of search URL](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/192854/custom-slug-in-front-of-search-url?rq=1)

Comment: I think you meant `$wp_rewrite->search_base = 'search-product';` and `add_action( 'search_rewrite_rules', 'search_rewrite_rules' );`.. But anyway, I'm glad you got it solved!

Comment: Well I meant `add_action( 'init', 'search_rewrite_rules' );`. xD (was off to bed and extremely sleepy at that time..)

Comment: Right! But I've figured it out ;) Thanks a lot for your support Sally!